# How to open a file in LibreOffice Writer from terminal and be back at terminal

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

How can I open a file in LibreOffice Writer from terminal and be back at terminal to continue with other tasks?

For instance, if I insert

> libreoffice CV*.odt

it will open the file in LibreOffice but I will be unable to proceed with further commands in that instance of terminal.

Comment: see this one for more tips too [Regain control after opening firefox via terminal](//askubuntu.com/q/802428)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple:

```
libreoffice CV*.odt &
```

The & at the end tells the terminal to run it in the background.

Comment: FYI as you are new here, if my answer was helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I accepted the answer but I still can't vote. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `xdg-open` utility which comes with a standard Ubuntu Desktop install will do this.  It works not only for LibreOffice documents, but for any file or URL.

`xdg-open` opens the file with your preferred application, and returns immediately:

```
xdg-open CV*.odt
```

**Tip:** add `alias o=xdg-open` to `~/.bash_aliases` to have a convenient shortcut:

```
o CV*.odt
o 'https://askubuntu.com/'
```